# Rephrase a question with not awarded bounty

Tags: support, bounties

I put a question with a [bounty](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/directory-of-national-postdoctoral-grants) but it seems nobody will even answer it. So my question is whether I can reuse this bounty to rephrase the question in some other way.

Comment: No. we can't. :(

Comment: You still have 22 hours to make whatever changes that might help. But: only for the same question indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounty is not refundable. It is the price to get attention for your question.

But you can always improve **that** question. Edit it to make it better. It will be pushed in the *Active Questions* queue too.